# add style to div generated by html2pdf.js

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

[html2pdf.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js) is a package for generating pdf's from html it is based on `jspdf` and `html2canvas`. It has a nice feature where it can [insert page-breaks](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js#page-breaks) in order not to split elements. The way it works is that it [loops over all the elements and creates empty div's](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/blob/db15497e3c134427d1473bb86b3b683e0e6dba8f/src/plugin/pagebreaks.js#L117) where a page break needs to be inserted. I would like to style those divs and instead of having blank white space would like to be able to insert a class to determine how they would look. The issue is I don't seem to have access to this new HTML that will be converted to a pdf. The API seems to indicate that this is possible [here](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js#advanced-usage) but when I put in code like this:

```
var worker = html2pdf();
                worker.set(opt).from(finalHtml).toContainer().toCanvas().then(newHtml => {
                    console.log(newHtml)
                    return newHtml
                })
```

I am getting `undefined`. This is true whether I chain to `toCanvas()` and `toContainer` or not. Basically I would like the html generated [here](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/blob/db15497e3c134427d1473bb86b3b683e0e6dba8f/src/plugin/pagebreaks.js#L117), how do I access this?